# Application code update on Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set (VMSS)

Tags: azure

Currently, we are hosting five websites on a Linux VM. The websites reside in their separate directories and are hosted by Nginx. The SSL is terminated at Azure Application gateway which sends the traffic to the VM. If a file is updated in a remote repository, the local copy is updated by a cron task which is a simple Bash script running git pull and few additional lines. Not all five websites need to be updated at the same time.
We created the image of the VM and provisioned a VMSS set up.
What could be the easiest or standard way of deploying the codes to the VMSS? The codes also need some manual changes each time due to client's requirements.

Comment: It really depends on how you apply the manual changes

Comment: In this case, the preferred method is to find the manual changes and port to the new version manually by logging in to the server.

Comment: There are plenty of different deployment techniques available OOTB in visual studio and through 3rd parties. I would say the easiest in terms of effort is to use specifically coded deployment templates in VS, but the concept of _easy_ is subjective. So please be more specific about what you want assistance with, do you want to _automate_ or _script_ the deployment process or do you have something else in mind

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into [Azure *Durable* Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#application-patterns) as an active scripted deployment manager.

You can configure your *Durable Function* to be triggered via a *cron* schedule, then it can orchestrate a series of tasks, monitoring for responses from the deployment targets for acceptable response before continuing each step or even waiting for user input to proceed.

By authoring your complex workflow using either of C#/JavaScript/Python/PowerShell you are only limited by your own ability to transform your *manual* process into a scripted one.

> Azure Functions is just one option of many, it really comes down to the complexity of your workflow and the individual tasks. [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/) is a common product used to automate Azure application deployments and may have templates that match your current process, I go straight to Durable Functions when I find it too hard to configure complex steps that involve waiting for specific responses from targets before proceeding to the next step, and I want to use C# to evaluate those responses or perhaps reuse some of my application logic as part of the workflow.

Comment: Thanks for sharing about Azure Durable Functions. Since the VMs are temporary in VMSS setup, do you mean to apply the functions to the image? Is that possible?

In my case, some of the tasks are really tribal and the Functions look a bit overkill. For example, after each upgrade I need to add a new random password supplied by the client to the application and the client does not want us to add that to vaults or repository.

Comment: No I am suggesting you create a set of Durable functions that exist only to perform your deployment of your existing code. We know nothing about what you code is or what the changes are, we don't even know what language or framework you are using, so I can only suggest methods that have the most extreme flexibility in terms of configuration. It doesn't get more extreme than writing an app in the form of functions to mimic what is currently a manual process for you.